# CookieManager.getCookie() returns null

Tags: android, post, cookies, webview, android-webview

I have some http requests. One of them retrieves and parse cookie from it's response. I save this cookie via CookieSyncManager and CookieManager with following code:

```
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
            CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
            cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
            cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
            String cookieString = cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue();
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), cookieString);
            cookieManager.setCookie(START_PAYMENT_URL, cookieString);
            CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Get cookie: " + cookieManager.getCookie(START_PAYMENT_URL));
```

Both Log.e calls write same cookie. So everything looks ok.

I have different activity which contains WebView. I need to call `postUrl(String url)` method with some POST params and with authorization cookie. I thought that cookie is in CookieManager and everything should work great. Well. It is. But on 4.x devices only.

On 2.x devices WebView makes postUrl without cookie.

Here is activity code which contains WebView:

```
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.payment_webview);

        final String billId = getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_BILL_ID);

        final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.payment_webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e(getClass().toString(), url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });

        String postData = "id_bill=" + billId;
        Log.d(TAG, "Requesting payment URL " + START_PAYMENT_URL + " with post data: " + postData);
        Log.d(TAG, CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(START_PAYMENT_URL));
        webView.postUrl(START_PAYMENT_URL, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
    }
```

CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(START_PAYMENT_URL) returns `null` on 2.x devices and cookie value on 4.x devices.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I figured out what's the problem.

I just removed

```
cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

while I'm saving cookies.

I suppose that problem is that all methods of `CookieManager` work asynchronously. Probably remove cookies methods invoked after `cookieManager.setCookie(START_PAYMENT_URL, cookieString);` even if they called before it. So `CookieManager` saves cookies and after that remove cookies methods invoked.